# Find similar estimate for complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, alternative-proof, complex-integration, elliptic-integrals

According to [Borwein](https://www.math.ust.hk/~machiang/education/enhancement/arithmetic_geometric.pdf), page 356 Prop. 2,

$\left|\ln\left(\frac{4}{k}\right)-\operatorname{I}(1,k)\right|\leq 4k^2\left(8+\left|\ln k\right|\right)$

holds for $k\in\left(0,1\right]$.
$I(1,k)=K(k')$ is the Complete Elliptic Integral of the first kind [(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind).

I need to find a similar estimate for complex numbers but Borwein uses Mean Value Theorem, which is not applicable for complex numbers.
To find something similar I think one has to restrict oneself to complex numbers with positiv real part and absolute value smaller than 1.
Would be great, if somebody provided a different approach or idea!

Comment: The mean value theorem in the form $$\lvert f(z) - f(w)\rvert \leqslant \lvert z-w\rvert\cdot \sup \{ \lvert f'(\zeta)\rvert : \zeta \in [w,z]\},$$ where $[w,z]$ is the segment between $w$ and $z$, also holds for complex functions.